# Redis does not improving performance

Tags: magento-1.9, database, redis, aws, jmeter

I'm trying to find the best setup for one really slow site.
For education purpose.

I set with **AWS CloudFront** like **full page cache**, not only static files.
Also **Varnish** and **Redis**, and performance are good now.

But I'm trying again to install one by and measure one by one and calculate what part giving more.

And I concluded that **Redis** does not improving at all. I tried with different pages, and nothing better. I also modified **AWS Redis** instance type to much stronger, and the same like the smallest one.
I checked and keys are stored in database 0 and 1.

Also metrics show that hits are OK
[image]

But when I try to test with **jmeter**, and hit 10 different links with 5 users, **MySQL CPU load** are go up to 100%.
I understand that main purpose of Redis is to serve cached query results to webserver, instead for every request to contact database server.

This is htop from mysql
[image]

Magento is 1.9.3.8
app/etc/modules/Cm_RedisSession.xml is set to true
And this is local.xml file regarding redis:

```
     <cache>
      <backend>Mage_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
      <backend_options>
        <server>xxxx.tapkyx.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com</server>              
        <port>6379</port>
        <persistent>cache-db0</persistent>
        <database>0</database>
        <password></password>
        <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
        <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
        <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
        <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
        <compress_data>1</compress_data>
        <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
        <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
      </backend_options>
    </cache>

 <session_save>db</session_save>
    <redis_session>
        <host>xxxx.tapkyx.0001.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com</host>            
        <port>6379</port>
        <password></password>
        <timeout>2.5</timeout>
        <persistent>cache-db1</persistent>
        <db>1</db>
        <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
        <log_level>4</log_level>
        <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>
        <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
        <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
        <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>
    </redis_session>
```

So questions are, what kind of improvements I can expect with using **redis**? And why is **MySQL CPU overloaded** even I call with **Jmeter** the same 10 pages?
Or what I forgot to do :).

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for why MySQL CPU is overloaded Answer.